# ITextSharp repeat HTML table header in PDF with using external css file

Tags: c#, itext

I have an HTML table in a view. I'm using ITextSharp to convert the
HTML to a PDF. I want to use external CSS and
repeat table header for each page. How do I get it to show the header
on each page using CSS and page header?

This is to show my page header

```
str.Append("<table class='text-center'>");
                    str.Append("<tr class='h4'><td> " + companyName + " </ td ></ tr >");
                    str.Append("</table>");
```

And this to show my HTML

```
TextReader xmlString = new StringReader(str.Append(html).ToString());
```

And this to append my CSS

```
ICSSResolver cssResolver = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().GetDefaultCssResolver(false);
cssResolver.AddCssFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Content/Print.css"), true);
IPipeline pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver,
    new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, new PdfWriterPipeline(document, writer)));

var worker = new XMLWorker(pipeline, true);
var xmlParse = new XMLParser(true, worker);
xmlParse.Parse(xmlString);
xmlParse.Flush();
```

This code work fine but
I am using 1 table for showing data and the table header does not repeat for
each page.  If i am using this code to repeat headers for table, the CSS does not
work. How can i resolve this issue, using both CSS and repeating header.

```
using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(html))
{
    List<IElement> elements =
      iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null);
    foreach (IElement el in elements)
    {
        if (el is PdfPTable)
        {
            ((PdfPTable)el).HeaderRows = 2;
        }
        document.Add(el);
        xmlParse.Parse(sr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

XML Worker allows you to configure repeating table headers and footers through proprietary CSS properties: `repeat-header` and `repeat-footer`. These are not part of the CSS specification.  They are only used by XML Worker for this specific purpose.

You can specify your header and footer rows using `<thead>` and `<tfoot>`.

```
<table style="repeat-header: yes; repeat-footer: yes;">
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Header 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Header 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- ... -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In your last code sample, you use `HTMLWorker`. You shouldn't. It's deprecated in favor of `XMLWorker`.

So just use your code based on `XMLWorker` and `XMLParser`, with the CSS property `repeat-header` as illustrated in the HTML sample above.

Comment: i am not understand your answer

Comment: Can you clarify what you don't understand? If you structure your HTML like I've shown in my answer, you'll get repeating table headers and footers. I have done the CSS inline (*style="repeat-header: yes; ..."*), but you can do the same with an external CSS file.

Comment: i want to repeat header using itextsharp this code work for me but css not work on this code                                                                        using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(html))
{
    List<IElement> elements =
      iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null);
    foreach (IElement el in elements)
    {
        if (el is PdfPTable)
        {
            ((PdfPTable)el).HeaderRows = 2;
        }
        document.Add(el);
        xmlParse.Parse(sr);
    }
}

Comment: You shouldn't use HTMLWorker anymore. It's deprecated in favor of XMLWorker. I'll update my answer.